# Select rows from Python DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, select, rows

I have got a Python DataFrame called "x" like this:

363108    05:01:00

363107    05:02:00

363106    05:03:00

363105    05:04:00

363104    05:05:00

```
        ...
```

4         16:57:00

3         16:58:00

2         16:59:00

1         17:00:00

0         17:01:00

The "time" column is string type.

I want to create a new DataFrame called "m" from all the rows in "x" such that the minute is "00".

I have tried m = x.loc[x["time"][3:5] == "00"] but I get "IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)."

Does anybody know how to do this please?

Comment: Have you tried converting your time string into timestamp using pandas and then use the "resample" function at the minute level ?

Comment: I dont even know what youre talking about. I guess that the solution to my problem is more simple.

Comment: if you are not familiar with pandas time series you can use REGEX : x.str.replace('(:\d{2})',':00').

Answer (score 1):

One way can be that you can create a new column in the existing dataframe that has the minutes field, which you can slice from the time column

```
df['minutes']=df['time'][-2:]
other_df=df.loc[df['minutes']=="00"]
```

Comment: Thanks Syed. I think this could work too, but the answer from GuiGNG is simpler and worked like a charm. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "apply" for the condition.

```
x.loc[x["time"].apply(lambda s: s[3:5] == "00")]
```

*In your code you are getting the range [3:5] on time Series(row 3 to 5)

Comment: Perfect. It worked like a charm. I was gettin rows 3 to 5 in x, thats why the code didnt work. Thanks a lot.